# Thread unable to join for_each parallel c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

I wrote a sample code to run parallel instances of for_each
I am unable to join the threads, in the below code. I am little early to concurrent programming so im not sure if i have done everything right.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename F>
class for_each_block
{
public :
        void operator()(Iterator start, Iterator end, F f) {
            cout << this_thread::get_id << endl;
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
            for_each(start, end, [&](auto& x) { f(x); });
    }
};

typedef unsigned const long int ucli;

template <typename Iterator, typename F>
void for_each_par(Iterator first, Iterator last, F f)
{
    ucli size = distance(first, last);
    if (!size)
        return;
    ucli min_per_thread = 4;
    ucli max_threads = (size + min_per_thread - 1) / min_per_thread;
    ucli hardware_threads = thread::hardware_concurrency();

    ucli no_of_threads = min(max_threads, hardware_threads != 0 ? hardware_threads : 4);

    ucli block_size = size / no_of_threads;

    vector<thread> vf(no_of_threads);
    Iterator block_start = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < (no_of_threads - 1); i++)
    {
        Iterator end = first;
        advance(end, block_size);
        vf.push_back(std::move(thread(for_each_block<Iterator, F>(),first,end,f)));
        first = end;
    }
    vf.push_back(std::move(thread(for_each_block<Iterator, F>(), first, last, f)));
    cout << endl;
    cout << vf.size() << endl;
    for(auto& x: vf)
    {
        if (x.joinable())
            x.join();
        else
            cout << "threads not joinable " << endl;
    }

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(100));
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = { 1,8,12,5,4,9,20,30,40,50,10,21,34,33 };
    for_each_par(v1.begin(), v1.end(), print_type<int>);
return 0;
}
```

In the above code i am getting threads not joinable. I have also tried with async futures still i get the same. Am i missing something here?

Any help is greatly appreciated ,
Thank you in advance ..

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<thread> vf(no_of_threads);
```

This creates a vector with `no_of_threads` default-initialized threads. Since they're default initialized, none of them will be joinable. You probably meant to do:

```
vector<thread> vf;
vf.reserve(no_of_threads);
```

P.S.: `std::move` on a temporary is redundant :); consider changing this:

```
vf.push_back(std::move(thread(for_each_block<Iterator, F>(), first, last, f)));
```

to this:

```
vf.emplace_back(for_each_block<Iterator, F>(), first, last, f);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. But i have one problem. All threads print same id. Can you also please suggest more(im sure i might have done somethings wrong way). Also i always had confusion for push_back and emplace_back thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @KartikV `this_thread::get_id` is a function, and it should be called. Right now you are printing function pointer value.

Comment: @Ocelot so true, i feel so stupid. both of you have opened my eyes. I should look close and clear to avoid silly mistakes. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be interesting. I had a go at refactoring the code to use what I think is a more idiomatic approach. I'm not saying that your approach is wrong, but since you're learning thread management I thought you may be interested in what else is possible.

Feel free to flame/question as appropriate. Comments inline:

```
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iomanip>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

//
// provide a means of serialising writing to a stream.
//
struct locker
{
    locker() : _lock(mutex()) {}

    static std::mutex& mutex() { static std::mutex m; return m; }
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const locker& l) {
    return os;
}

//
// fill in the missing work function
//
template<class T>
void print_type(const T& t) {
    std::cout << locker() << hex << std::this_thread::get_id() << " : " << dec << t << std::endl;
}

// put this in your personable library.
// the standards committee really should have given us ranges by now...
template<class I1, class I2>
struct range_impl
{
    range_impl(I1 i1, I2 i2) : _begin(i1), _end(i2) {};

    auto begin() const { return _begin; }
    auto end() const { return _end; }

    I1 _begin;
    I2 _end;
};

// distinct types because sometimes dissimilar iterators are comparable
template<class I1, class I2>
auto range(I1 i1, I2 i2) {
    return range_impl<I1, I2>(i1, i2);
}

//
// lets make a helper function so we can auto-deduce template args
//
template<class Iterator, typename F>
auto make_for_each_block(Iterator start, Iterator end, F&& f)
{
    // a lambda gives all the advantages of a function object with none
    // of the boilerplate.
    return [start, end, f = std::move(f)] {
        cout << locker() << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

        // let's keep loops simple. for_each is a bit old-skool.
        for (auto& x : range(start, end)) {
            f(x);
        }
    };
}


template <typename Iterator, typename F>
void for_each_par(Iterator first, Iterator last, F f)
{
    if(auto size = distance(first, last))
    {
        std::size_t min_per_thread = 4;
        std::size_t max_threads = (size + min_per_thread - 1) / min_per_thread;
        std::size_t hardware_threads = thread::hardware_concurrency();

        auto no_of_threads = min(max_threads, hardware_threads != 0 ? hardware_threads : 4);

        auto block_size = size / no_of_threads;

        // futures give us two benefits:
        // 1. they automatically transmit exceptions
        // 2. no need for if(joinable) join. get is sufficient
        //
        vector<future<void>> vf;
        vf.reserve(no_of_threads - 1);
        for (auto count = no_of_threads ; --count ; )
        {
            //
            // I was thinking of refactoring this into std::generate_n but actually
            // it was less readable.
            //
            auto end = std::next(first, block_size);
            vf.push_back(async(launch::async, make_for_each_block(first, end, f)));
            first = end;
        }
        cout << locker() << endl << "threads: " << vf.size()  << " (+ main thread)" << endl;

        //
        // why spawn a thread for the remaining block? we may as well use this thread
        //
        /* auto partial_sum = */ make_for_each_block(first, last, f)();

        // join the threads
        // note that if the blocks returned a partial aggregate, we could combine them
        // here by using the values in the futures.
        for (auto& f : vf) f.get();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = { 1,8,12,5,4,9,20,30,40,50,10,21,34,33 };
    for_each_par(v1.begin(), v1.end(), print_type<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
0x700000081000
0x700000104000

threads: 3 (+ main thread)
0x700000187000
0x100086000
0x700000081000 : 1
0x700000104000 : 5
0x700000187000 : 20
0x100086000 : 50
0x700000081000 : 8
0x700000104000 : 4
0x700000187000 : 30
0x100086000 : 10
0x700000081000 : 12
0x700000104000 : 9
0x700000187000 : 40
0x100086000 : 21
0x100086000 : 34
0x100086000 : 33
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

> please explain std::move here: `[start, end, f = std::move(f)] {...};`

This is a welcome language feature that was made available in c++14. `f = std::move(f)` inside the capture block is equivalent to: `decltype(f) new_f = std::move(f)` except that the new variable is called `f` and not `new_f`. It allows us to `std::move` objects into lambdas rather than copy them.

For most function objects it won't matter - but some can large and this gives the compiler the opportunity to use a move rather than a copy if available.

Comment: It is very neat, locker, range are really cool. Can you please explain the move semantics you used for the function argument?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your helper functions are really useful, can u point me to any blog with more of such?(or may be you can write one if you get time )

Comment: @KartikV hmm. I tend not to follow c++ blogs. Most of them seem to be written by people who don't know the language very well. Ping me on hodges.r@gmail.com with questions, or you can have a look at some of my other answers here. There are some serious c++ experts on stack overflow. if I come across something I'll let you know. I have been thinking about running some courses when my next piece of work is finished (hopefully within he month).